# Calculating the prorata of employee calls per Business Unit in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am establishing business rules to determine the number of active call center agents per 30 minutes intervals.

We have 2 types of agents: **Billing** & **Technical Ops**.

We've recently let billing agents take technical calls, and vice-versa.

I have written the following code that returns the call count per agent, per interval and per call type:

```
SELECT 
    HAGENT.[ROW_DATE],
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN([STARTTIME]) = 1 THEN '00:00'
       WHEN LEN([STARTTIME]) = 2 THEN '00:30'
       WHEN LEN([STARTTIME]) = 3 THEN (LEFT([STARTTIME],1) + ':' + RIGHT([STARTTIME],2))
       WHEN LEN([STARTTIME]) = 4 THEN (LEFT([STARTTIME],2) + ':' + RIGHT([STARTTIME],2)) 
    END AS THETIME,
    ([LOGID]) AS AGENTS,
    COUNT(HAGENT.ACDCALLS) AS CALL_COUNT,
    CASE 
       WHEN SPLITMATRIX.[Business_Unit] LIKE '%Billing%' THEN 'CDN Billing'
       WHEN SPLITMATRIX.[Business_Unit] LIKE '%TechOps%' THEN 'CDN Tech Ops' 
    END AS Bunit
FROM 
    [KPI_DATA].[dbo].[DM_CMS_HAGENT] HAGENT
LEFT JOIN 
    [GEMDB].[dbo].[T_PRD_REF_xAGENT_AGENTLIST] AGENTLIST 
        ON AGENTLIST.asp_raw_cmsID1 = HAGENT.LOGID  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
        AND HAGENT.ROW_DATE BETWEEN AGENTLIST.[asp_raw_START_SDEPT] AND AGENTLIST.asp_raw_STOP_SDEPT
        AND HAGENT.ROW_DATE BETWEEN AGENTLIST.[asp_raw_START_TEAM] AND AGENTLIST.[asp_raw_STOP_TEAM]
LEFT JOIN 
    [MATRIX_DATA].[dbo].[REF_CMS_SPLIT_MATRIX] SPLITMATRIX
        ON SPLITMATRIX.SPLIT = HAGENT.SPLIT
WHERE
    ROW_DATE >= '2017-07-01' 
    AND [ACDCALLS] != 0 
    AND (SPLITMATRIX.[Business_Unit] LIKE '%Billing%' 
         OR SPLITMATRIX.[Business_Unit] LIKE '%TechOps%')
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS (
         (ROW_DATE, STARTTIME,([LOGID]), SPLITMATRIX.[Business_Unit]),
         (ROW_DATE, STARTTIME,([LOGID]))
    )
ORDER BY 
    ROW_DATE DESC, THETIME DESC, [LOGID] DESC
```

The output looks like this:

[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzN2H.jpg)

With AGENTS being the unique logid of an agent, Bunit the type of Calls taken (When Bunit is NULL, it's the total number of calls taken by an agent for that interval).

From this output, I would like to calculate an active employee count per interval & Calls Types.

For example, if an agent took 2 Billing Calls & 1 Tech Ops Call, I would consider that 2/3 of this agent was working as a Billing Agent, and 1/3 of this agent was a Tech Ops agent.

Finally I would like to group the SUM of the agents ratio per Call types, per interval.

I tried using a PIVOT function, without luck.

My expected result would look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKiUl.jpg

Any help?

Comment: Can you show us your expected result?

Comment: Hi,my expected result would look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKiUl.jpg
it's basically a prorata of our active agents based on the # of call types they took.

Comment: how about some sample data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PIVOT and UNPIVOT on this scenario

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE t_bu
(row_date DATE,
 thetime TIME,
 agents INT,
 call_count INT,
 bunit VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO t_bu VALUES
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210893,1,'CDN Billing'),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210893,1,NULL),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210870,2,'CDN Tech Ops'),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210870,2,NULL),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210858,3,'CDN Billing'),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210858,3,NULL),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210857,1,'CDN Tech Ops'),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210857,1,NULL),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210849,1,'CDN Billing'),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210849,1,NULL),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210832,2,'CDN Billing'),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210832,1,'CDN Tech Ops'),
('8/17/2017','9:30',1210832,3,NULL),
('10/21/2017','10:30',1210857,3,'CDN Tech Ops'),
('10/21/2017','10:30',1210857,3,NULL),
('10/21/2017','12:30',1210857,3,'CDN Tech Ops'),
('10/21/2017','12:30',1210857,3,NULL),
('10/21/2017','12:30',1210849,4,'CDN Billing'),
('10/21/2017','12:30',1210849,4,NULL),
('10/21/2017','12:30',1210832,3,'CDN Billing'),
('10/21/2017','12:30',1210832,5,'CDN Tech Ops'),
('10/21/2017','12:30',1210832,8,NULL);
```

SQL Query (Dynamic)

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CASE WHEN t.bunit IS NULL THEN 'Total' ELSE t.bunit END) 
                     FROM t_bu t -- use your table name
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @query = 'WITH t_comp AS
              (SELECT row_date, thetime, SUM(CAST([CDN Billing] AS FLOAT)/CAST([Total] AS FLOAT)) [CDN Billing], SUM(CAST([CDN Tech Ops] AS FLOAT)/CAST([Total] AS FLOAT)) [CDN Tech Ops]
                 FROM (SELECT agents, row_date, thetime, ' + @cols + 
             '           FROM (SELECT agents, 
                                      row_date,
                                      thetime,
                                      CASE WHEN bunit IS NULL THEN ''Total'' ELSE bunit END AS bunit,
                                      call_count
                                 FROM t_bu -- use your table name
                              ) x
                        PIVOT (MAX(call_count)
                          FOR bunit in (' + @cols + ')) p 
                      ) a
                GROUP BY row_date, thetime
               )
               SELECT row_date, thetime, call_type, active_agents
                 FROM t_comp
               UNPIVOT (active_agents
                   FOR call_type IN ([CDN Billing], [CDN Tech Ops])) u'

EXECUTE(@query)
 GO
```

Result

```
row_date    thetime             call_type       active_agents
2017-08-17  09:30:00.0000000    CDN Billing     3.66666666666667
2017-08-17  09:30:00.0000000    CDN Tech Ops    2.33333333333333
2017-10-21  10:30:00.0000000    CDN Tech Ops    1
2017-10-21  12:30:00.0000000    CDN Billing     1.375
2017-10-21  12:30:00.0000000    CDN Tech Ops    1.625
```

Comment: This was based on the SQL Output you provided since we do not have your sample raw data (from your original tables that you used on your SQL) . I think, it would be more efficient if we will have the desired result using those data instead.

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand. So far this seems to work fine. Thank you so much!